Run qcow2 image created with virt-manager using qemu-system-x86_64
My qemu version is QEMU emulator version 9.0.2 (Debian 1:9.0.2+ds-2+b1).
I created a FreeBSD 14 VM using virt-manager. It's drive is a qcow2 image:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 libvirt-qemu libvirt-qemu 8.1G 20240916 20:26:09.201 bsdie.qcow2

I am a member of the appropriate group:
groups
localuser cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev kvm netdev bluetooth scanner lpadmin libvirt libvirt-qemu

However, I get a permissions error when trying to run this machine using CLI:
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -enable-kvm -m 1G -drive file=bsdie.qcow2  -net nic,vlan=0,macaddr=52:54:00:81:b6:cc -net user 
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=bsdie.qcow2: Could not open 'bsdie.qcow2': Permission denied

What am I missing?
More generally, I'd like to know if there is a way of running machines defined via virt-manager using Qemu cmd. line; since the XML config files can be found in /etc/libvirt/qemu, I'd like to know if there is a way of "translating" the XML parameters into Qemu command-line args.
Thanks!

The permissions on the file are read only for the group membership.
-rwxr-xr-x 1 libvirt-qemu libvirt-qemu 8.1G 20240916 20:26:09.201 bsdie.qcow2

This means you can't open the file for writing even though you are in the group.  chmod g+w should fix this.
In general machines created with virt-manager can be managed from the command line with the virsh command.
e.g.
$ sudo ls /etc/libvirt/qemu                                                    
autostart  build9.xml  networks  pinky9.xml  plexserver9.xml  test9.xml

$ virsh list --all
 Id   Name          State
------------------------------
 1    pinky9        running
 2    plexserver9   running
 -    build9        shut off
 -    test9         shut off

$ virsh start test9
Domain 'test9' started

$ virsh list --all
 Id   Name          State
------------------------------
 1    pinky9        running
 2    plexserver9   running
 3    test9         running
 -    build9        shut off


This solves the problem. Thanks! I'd just like to know whether it is possible to run the VM using qemu-system and how to interpret the configs in the XML file as qemu command-line parameters; I'm curious. For example, running the above command launches the VM but I have no internet access.

Once you've started the process with virsh you can always do a ps and see what paramters it's using :-)
